# How to search imap inbox with mailkit based on multiple condition?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mailkit

I want to search imap inbox  with mailkit  based on multiple condition like NotSeen & NotDeleted. I know the queries are receptively,if we do individual search query.

```
var uids = client.Inbox.Search(SearchQuery.NotSeen); 
var uids = client.Inbox.Search(SearchQuery.NotDeleted );
```

but i need to put those two queries together & get all Uids based  on the conditions.
 Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can combine search queries using the And() and/or Or():

```
var uids = client.Inbox.Search (SearchQuery.NotSeen.And (SearchQuery.NotDeleted));
```

or

```
var uids = client.Inbox.Search (SearchQuery.And (SearchQuery.NotSeen, SearchQuery.NotDeleted));
```

Comment: Thanks For the reply... great answer :)

Comment: What if i need to serach/Get first 10 email base on SearchQuery?

Comment: @ParthAkbari You have 2 options. Either use the `Search` method as above, but just use the first 10 uids (assuming you want the default ordering)... or you can construct the `SearchQuery` the same as above, but then specify your own sort ordering and then call the [Sort](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/M_MailKit_Net_Imap_ImapFolder_Sort_1.htm) method instead (which returns the same results as `Search`, but in whatever order you ask for). For example: `var uids = folder.Sort (query, new OrderBy[] { OrderBy.ReverseArrival });`

Answer (score 2):

This snippet adds an conditional search condition *after* the main query has been set

```
var query = MailKit.Search.SearchQuery.FromContains("anyone@gmail.com")
                            .And(MailKit.Search.SearchQuery.SubjectContains("Your Subject"));

query = query .And(MailKit.Search.SearchQuery.DeliveredAfter(DateTime.Parse("2020-02-28")));
```

Answer (score 0):

ok i found a way to manage it. Please suggest me if you have better way.

```
            var unread = client.Inbox.Search(SearchQuery.NotSeen);
            var Deleted = client.Inbox.Search(SearchQuery.Deleted);
            var Res  = unread.Except(Deleted).ToList();
```