# Read Google Mail Box through Search Filter like Date

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I think my question is a bit off. I read **Google Mailbox** via `MailKit` Thanks to this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19570553/9049282). I want to read a mailbox with a search filter from-date to end-date.

*E.g I want to read emails for **June 2020** month like that*

I have a lot of searches but failed to get enough information. Please help in this regard.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61281567/8772744 try this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass your search query to Gmail like this:

```
private MessageCollection GetMails(string mailBox, string searchPhrase, DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {
        string dateRange = $"after:{start.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")} before:{end.AddDays(1).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")}";
        string searchQuery = $"{dateRange} {searchPhrase}";
        Mailbox mails = Client.SelectMailbox(mailBox);
        MessageCollection messages = mails.SearchParse(searchQuery);
        return messages;
    }
```

Comment: you didn't pass the `dateRange` variable to `searchQuery`?

Comment: I did. <string searchQuery = $"{dateRange} {searchPhrase}">

Comment: I get `Command "search after:2022/09/13 before:2022/09/14 ALL" failed : 220914124625978 BAD Could not parse command` exception